# Open dialog at the center of the screen, windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using the System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog() method, the problem is that it always opens at the top left or right corner of my application, depending on the Right to Left layout. Is it possible to center it in the middle of the screen or application?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using a Form, you can use [Form.StartPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx).
And here is more about this enumeration: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formstartposition.aspx)